# Getting a Inserting Duplicate Key Error when value doesn't exist in table- SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

We've got a web application that takes a uniquely generated workshop ID and calls a procedure (using php) and this procedure inserts it into a sql server table. This table has a clustered index on column workshopID and is set to unique.

This morning we had a user report that he got the following error code on his page:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.table with unique
>   index 'ClusteredIndex-Wrkshp'. The duplicate key value is (Z9C1Am)

Obviously this suggests that I'm trying to insert Z9C1Am into the table and that value already exists---HOWEVER, when we do a simple lookup on that value, this value did not exist so I took the same stored procedure that the website code calls and used it to inserted Z9C1Am (using SSMS) into the table without any problem.

I can also get onto this application without any problems with this error; however, this same user called again and said he had the same issue (on the same computer) in another session.  This time it had a different wordshopID in the error, but once again, this did not exist in the database.

I don't believe this has anything to do with inserting a duplicate key, rather, it is a phantom error.

Any suggestions on how to confirm this and how to track the actual error?
 My gut reaction is this must be a browser related problem; however, all the code that interacts with the sql database is server side so this theory doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Doubt it is a phantom error.  I would check for triggers on the underlying tables involved.

Comment: Thanks Greg--I just checked and I don't have any triggers.

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose if the error isn't consistently reproducible.  Run a Profiler Trace on the server and when the error occurs, check the Trace to verify it is happening on the server you suspect, and not on another server that the user is somehow accessing.

Comment: Maybe a race condition? If you're checking, and then inserting, it could be inserted between the check and the insert.

Comment: @Larnu except if it had been a race condition, wouldn't the OP find the row with the value in the error message when looking later?   Unless this is data that also gets deleted...

Comment: Just throwing ideas out, in truth @TabAlleman. Could even be that the OP is using some kind of `JOIN` to generate the full `INSERT` statement, however, due to unexpected data it created a duplicate; thus 2 rows trying to be inserted with the same key. *If* that did happen then neither row would exist and the whole transaction would be rolled back. Without a replicable scenario best we can really offer are guesses. :)

Comment: Ha, never mind, that *was* indeed the problem. (Only managed to post that 11 seconds before the OP did, so *hopefully* my crystal ball for the week isn't used up as the OP would have found the issue as I was typing.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses guys!

Greg's comment made me start looking harder at my dependencies and I have a join statement inside of my insert statement.  The table I was joining to was supposed to contain unique values and approx. 25,000 of them are; however I had one set of duplicates causing the error.